# 'Subs' is not defined error when trying to graph the tangent line of the derivative of my function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, sympy

I've graphed my original function and I want to graph the tangent line at the point of interest.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import lambdify, symbols, diff, Abs

point_of_interest = 8
graphRange = [1,15]

# define the variable and the function
xsym = symbols('x')

# With a chord length of 60, plot the circle diameters
origFunction = 2 * ((60 ** 2) / (8 * Abs(xsym)) + Abs(xsym) / 2)

# define the derivative
derivative = diff(origFunction, xsym)

# define the tangent line at point of interest
tangentLine = derivative.subs(xsym, point_of_interest) * (xsym - point_of_interest) + origFunction.subs(xsym, point_of_interest)

# Convert the SymPy function to a lambda function
origF = lambdify(xsym, origFunction, "numpy")

# Generate x values
x_values = np.linspace(graphRange[0], graphRange[1], 100)

# Generate y-values for the original function
y_values = origF(x_values)

# Plot the original function
plt.plot(x_values, y_values, label='Original Function')

# THIS SECTION DOESN'T WORK YET
# Convert the SymPy function to a lambda function
diffF = lambdify(xsym, tangentLine, "numpy")

# Generate y-values for the tangent line
y_tang_values = diffF(x_values)

# Plot the tangent line
plt.plot(x_values, y_tang_values, label='Tangent Line')

#plot the point of interest
plt.plot(point_of_interest, origF(point_of_interest), 'ro', label='Point of Interest')

# Add labels and legend
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Graph of Original Function and Tangent Line')
plt.legend()

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

The error I get is this

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "x:\Python Projects\Chord calc.py", line 37, in 
y_tang_values = diffF(x_values)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "", line 4, in _lambdifygenerated
NameError: name 'Subs' is not defined

I don't know what to do to fix this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, you are using a complex symbol, `xsym`: it doesn't have any assumptions, hence it is as general as it gets.

Your function contains `Abs(xsym)`: because `xsym` is complex, its derivative will be quite convoluted:

```py
print(Abs(xsym).diff(xsym))
# (re(x)*Derivative(re(x), x) + im(x)*Derivative(im(x), x))*sign(x)/x
```

Once you substitutes a numeric value into that expression, `Subs` appears, and you get the error later on.

The solution is simple: create a real symbol. Replace this line:

```py
xsym = symbols('x')
```

with:

```py
xsym = symbols('x', real=True)
```

Then, everything will work as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Subs` is still in the `tangentLine` expression:

```
In [64]: tangentLine
Out[64]: 
-209*(x - 8)*Subs(Derivative(re(x), x), x, 8)/16 + 241/2
```

The `doc` (help) for the generated function is:

```
In [66]: print(diffF.__doc__)
Created with lambdify. Signature:

func(x)

Expression:

-209*(x - 8)*Subs(Derivative(re(x), x), x, 8)/16 + 241/2

Source code:

def _lambdifygenerated(x):
    return (  # Not supported in Python with numpy:
  # Derivative
-209/16*(x - 8)*Subs(Derivative(re(x), x), x, 8) + 241/2)
```

It complains that `Derivative` isn't defined for `numpy`, but neither is `Subs`.  `lambdify` does a fairly shallow translation from `sympy` to `python/numpy`,  SO questions about `lambdify` problems are common, though it's unlikely that anyone else has tried a similar expression.  A web search on `sympy lambdify` may turn up something useful, but not if you focus on `Subs`.

The lambdify for `origF` is much simpler:

```
func(x)    
Expression:    
Abs(x) + 900/Abs(x)    
Source code:    
def _lambdifygenerated(x):
    return abs(x) + 900/abs(x)
```

And with `real` x as suggested by the other answer, the expression and lambdify doc is:

```
func(x)    
Expression:
225 - 209*x/16
Source code:
def _lambdifygenerated(x):
    return 225 - 209/16*x
```